# ASP.Net Core HTTP Request Connections getting stuck

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

We have a simple application in ASP.NET Core which calls a website and returns the content. The Controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("test/get")]
public ActionResult<string> TestGet()
{
    var client = new WebClient
    {
        BaseAddress = "http://v-dev-a"
    };
    return client.DownloadString("/");
}
```

The URL which we call is just the default page of an IIS. I am using Apache JMeter to test 1000 requests in 10 seconds. I have always the same issue, after about 300-400 requests it gets stuck for a few minutes and nothing works. The appplication which holds the controller is completely frozen.
In the performance monitor (MMC) I see that the connection are at 100%.

I tried the same code with ASP.NET 4.7.2 and it runs without any issues.

I also read about that the dispose of the WebClient does not work and I should make it static. See [here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)
Also the deactivation of the KeepAlive did not help:

```
public class QPWebClient : WebClient
{
   protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   {
      var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
      if (request is HttpWebRequest)
      {
         ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
      }
      return request;
   }
}
```

The [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-2.2) hast the same issue, it does not change anything

With dependency injection like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634015/httpclient-reuse-in-mvc-net-core-web-app-with-multiple-apis-and-querystrings) there is an exception throw that the web client can't handle more request at the same time.

Another unsuccessful try was to change ConnectionLimit and SetTcpKeepAlive in [ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1)

So I am out of ideas how to solve this issue. Last idea is to move the application to ASP.NET. Does anyone of you have an idea or faced already the same issue?

Comment: can you take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) about new HttpClientFactory

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I directly tried it and now i get after like 200 requests an error: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Comment: can you update your question with your latest code you used to try HttpClientFactory?

Comment: The issue was that is added this .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) to the ConfigureServices... I found a way so it works, will update my post soon. But thanks @CharmisVarghese